# Reactive Forms and @Input

Tags: angular, input, angular-reactive-forms

I want to make Reactiev Form with the values taken from other Component.
To pass data to Component I use @Input.

For example:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class GetData implements OnInit {
  @Input() dataToPass: DataOne;
  myForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required]],
... }
}
```

I want to see in HTML the form with data passed in Input.

Is it possible? Where should I pass the data to Form?

New code, after your hints:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes);

    if (changes['this.dataToPass'] && changes['this.dataToPass'].currentValue) {
      console.log('change');
    }

    if (changes['this.dataToPass'].firstChange === true) {
      console.log('Change is seen');
    }
}
```

First condition is not true.
Second one, I get the error:
 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChange' of undefined.

Next code:

```
if (changes['dataToPass'].firstChange && changes['dataToPass']) {
      console.log('Change is seen');
      console.log(this.dataToPass.firstName);
}
```

What I get is: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property firstName of undifined."

It looks like the Input happens after such changes.

Next code:

```
if (changes['dataToPass'].firstChange && changes['dataToPass']) {
      console.log('Change is seen');
      console.log(this.dataToPass);
}
```

And unluckily I get an information that it is undefined.
So it does not work as it should.

Comment: have you check my answer , do you still have a problem ?

Comment: Any update Guys? No idea why it does not work.

Comment: I think you are close , check my updated answer  and I have include a demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use these method `patchValue` , `setValue` ,`reset`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required]],
     ... 
    });

   this.myForm.patchValue(this.dataToPass);

}
```

> using patchValue or reset method will not throw an error if you don't
>   pass data to all controls

**Updated!! ⚡⚡**

```js
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    if (changes.dataToPass && changes.dataToPass.currentValue){
      this.myForm.patchValue(changes.dataToPass.currentValue)
    }

  }
```

this `ngOnChanges` will keep track of the `dataToPass` object has changes , but not object properties, you need to set the binding object to new object every time you update any proprty,to trigger change detection 
from parent component

```
this.userData = {...this.userData};
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6go27j)

Comment: Look on my last code. I cannot access Object sent from other component through @Input.

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass the whole FormGroup as input, like `@Input myForm: FormGroup` or you can pass an object that contains the data you want and patch them to your form.

For example, let's assume the form below,

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required]],
    surname: ['', [Validators.required]],
    age: ['', [Validators.required]],
       ...
   })
```

and an Object like

```
{
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'Black'
}
```

you can then pass this object to @Input
`@Input myData: {name:string,surname:string};`
and then patch your form like so

```
this.myForm.patchValue(myData);
```

Comment: Having gone down the rabbit hole of passing the formgroup myself I really don’t recommend this. It’s better to use typescript to define your models and patchValue